# How to write a service for MAC OS listens for keyboard shortcuts, when using this shortcut to open the corresponding app

Tags: macos, cocoa, hotkeys, appkit

I'm writing a MAC app, want to write a system service, when the program is not started, use this quick service button to start the program.Don't know whether with XPC service can implement this feature?